# is it possible to await for particular value in python/pytest

Tags: python, async-await, pytest, python-asyncio

Is it possible to wait till particular value is received from a function in python/pytest.

I have a function(for eg:test_val) which returns different values at different scenarios.
So I need to run a code when a particular value (for eg: 15) is returned from the function test_val.
Is it possible to await for value 15 with timeout? like I need to wait for 2 seconds, If within 2 seconds value 15 is received then a block of code can be run or else it is skipped.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For your situation, you can create a loop to continuously call the function until it returns the desired value or the time limit is reached. Here is a simple example of how you could do this:

```py
import time

def test_val():
    # Your function here
    return value

start_time = time.time()
timeout = 2.0  # timeout in seconds

while True:
    result = test_val()
    if result == 15:
        print("Value 15 received!")
        # run your block of code here
        break
    elif time.time() - start_time > timeout:
        print("Timeout reached")
        # handle timeout here
        break
```

This code will run the test_val function in a loop until either the function returns 15 or 2 seconds have passed.